# Problemas na tela de login

Tags: php

Estou iniciando na programação. E estou criando uma especie de agenda para a sala de reunião da empresa onde trabalho. Então estou um pouco travado na tela de login ainda. Fiz todo o processo.

Quando faço o login ele acessa normal, e também fiz esse código para segurança de não conseguirem acessar mudando o nome da pagina pela barra de endereços. Porem quando eu clico para fazer o login, nessa outra tela da agenda, se a linha 3 estiver com a negação (!) do `isset`, ele simplesmente não loga e se estiver sem a negação, exatamente como esta no código abaixo, ele funciona normalmente, mais também não bloqueia.
E quando eu tento clico no botão sair ele mostra uma mensagem de erro de permissão do wampserver apache forbiden.

AREA PRIVADA

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_session['id_usuario']))
    {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

TELA DA AGENDA

```
<a href="Sair.php>"> Sair</a>
```

TELA QUE REDIRECIONA PARA AREA PRIVADA

```
<?php
require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
$u = new Usuario;
?>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Projeto Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="corpo-form">
    <h1>Entrar</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuário">
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
        <input type="submit" value="Acessar">
        <a href="cadastrar.php">Ainda não é cadastrado? <strong>Cadastre-se!</strong>

    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);

        if(!empty($email) && !empty($senha))
        {
            $u->conectar("projeto_login","localhost","root","");
            if($u->msgErro == "")
            {
                if($u->logar($email,$senha))
                {
                    header("location: AreaPrivada.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="msg-erro">
                        "E-mail e/ou senha estão incorretos!"
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <div class="msg-erro">
                    <?php echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro; ?>
                </div>
                <?php           
            }   

        }else
        {
            ?>
            <div class="msg-erro">
            "Preencha todos os campos!"
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O correto é `$_SESSION` e não `$_session`, assim como `$_POST`, `$_GET`, entre outros

Comment: Obrigado cara, mais concertei essa questão das letras maiúsculas porem não resolveu, continua os mesmos erros.

Comment: No local onde você cria a variável de sessão também foi corrigido?

Comment: Sim, corrigi em todos.

` global $pdo;
  $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
  $sql->bindvalue(":e",$email);
  $sql->bindvalue(":s",md5($senha));
  $sql->execute();
  if($sql->rowcount() > 0)
  {
   $dado = $sql->fetch();
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dado['id_usuario'];
   return true; 
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }`